# mysql information_schema.columns missing data

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, catalog-views

i've a mysql 8.0.28 instance with a set of "broken" views.
When i run this query

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'vw_accounts';
Empty set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

i get no results, but if run this other one

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.views where table_name = 'vw_accounts';
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME  | VIEW_DEFINITION.                 | CHECK_OPTION | IS_UPDATABLE | DEFINER | SECURITY_TYPE | CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT | COLLATION_CONNECTION |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------
| def           | xxxx         | vw_accounts | select `acc`.`account_id` ...... | NONE         | NO           | root@%  | DEFINER       | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci  
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
```

the view seems to be defined.

When i query(`select * from vw_accounts`) the view it works correctly.

If i try to delete and redefine the broken view everything works again.

There are no errors in the logs and i run the mysqlcheck utility on all schemas without any warning/error.

Some ideas on how to investigate this issue and fix it without redefining the "broken" views.

Thanks.

### **EDIT after thread with @RickJames**

I've done some other checks and discovered that a view used in the `vw_accounts` has a weird definition(collaction_connection utf8mb4_general_ci) compared to other views:

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME     | VIEW_DEFINITION                  | CHECK_OPTION | IS_UPDATABLE | DEFINER        | SECURITY_TYPE | CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT | COLLATION_CONNECTION |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| def           | xxxx         | vw_accounts    | select `acc`.`account_id` ...... | NONE         | NO           | root@%         | DEFINER       | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      |
| def           | xxxx         | vw_identifiers | select ......................... | NONE         | NO           | root@%         | DEFINER       | utf8mb4              | utf8mb4_general_ci   |
```

After i redefine the vw_identifiers view the `collation_connection` began `utf8_genral_ci` and also the `vw_accounts` worked as expected.

Comment: When it says something like "1 warning", immediately do `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: @RickJames View 'xxxx.vw_accounts' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them .. i'm running the command with root user

Comment: If you can provide a small, _reproducible_, test case, file a bug:  bugs.mysql.com